# Android How to Animate Translate Inflate Layout set Start Magin From top

Tags: android, android-animation, layout-inflater

```
animation = new TranslateAnimation(
          Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
          Animation.ABSOLUTE, -300, Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0
```

I use this code. but i want magin top between start inflate layout and top screen.

how to code it.

Comment: You need to put your layout in xml with top margin.

Comment: @MurtazaHussain I add android:layout_marginTop="50dp" but not change when compile

Comment: @MurtazaHussain layout it start on top again

Comment: show your code, xml + java